# How to merge two sparse coo_matrix matrices in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Say, I have two coo_matrix (i,j) value:
mat_1:

```
 (0, 1)        0.5
 (0, 2)        0.5
 (1, 2)        1.0
 (3, 0)        0.5
 (3, 3)        0.5
 (5, 0)        0.5
 (5, 3)        0.5
```

mat_2:

```
 (2, 0)        0.25
 (4, 0)        0.25
 (2, 1)        0.25
 (4, 1)        0.25
 (2, 2)        0.25
 (4, 2)        0.25
 (2, 3)        0.25
 (4, 3)        0.25
```

I want to merge them together so that the output looks like this:

```
 (0, 1)        0.5
 (0, 2)        0.5
 (1, 2)        1.0
 (3, 0)        0.5
 (3, 3)        0.5
 (5, 0)        0.5
 (5, 3)        0.5
 (2, 0)        0.25
 (4, 0)        0.25
 (2, 1)        0.25
 (4, 1)        0.25
 (2, 2)        0.25
 (4, 2)        0.25
 (2, 3)        0.25
 (4, 3)        0.25
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Unless you want some special treatment for entries present in both matrices, adding them together should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of columns is the same of both sparse matrices you want to combine, you could try using `sparse.vstack`:

```
sparse.hstack((mat1, mat2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with mat_1, a coo_matrix with shape 6,4, and mat_2, another coo_matrix with shape 5,4.  (These shapes fit the data as presented.)

First, you need to resize mat_2 to match mat_1.  Then you add them together with a simple + operator.  The resulting matrix is csr instead of coo, so you cast it back.

```
mat_2.resize((6,4))
mat_3 = mat_1 + mat_2
mat_4 = mat_3.tocoo()
```